# How can I make a circular graph in Graphviz?

Tags: graph, graphviz, fsm

I have this following graph in graphviz:

[image]

That is generated from this code:

```
digraph finite_state_machine {
    rankdir=TB;
    node [shape = none]; Start;
    node [shape = circle];
    nodesep=.5;
    Start -> A;
    
    A->B
    B->C
    C->D
    D->E
    E->F
    F->G
    G->H
    H->I
    I->A

    {rank = same; A B C D}
    {rank = same; E}
    {rank = same; F G H I}
}
```

How can I change the direction of those bottom lines in order to make it look like that?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example with 8 nodes (as from your drawing it was not clear where to put the 9-th):

```
digraph finite_state_machine {
    rankdir=TB;
    node [shape = none]; Start;
    node [shape = circle];
    nodesep=.5;
    Start -> A;
    
    A->B
    B->C
    C->D
    D->E
    F->E [dir=back]
    G->F [dir=back]
    H->G [dir=back]
    A->H [dir=back]
   

    {rank = same; A B C }
    {rank = same;  E F G }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative approach, you could use a different layout engine than `dot` for this graph.

[`circo`](https://graphviz.org/docs/layouts/circo/) seems particularly appropriate, the result looks like this:

[image: circular layout of graph nodes]

But of course, you may try other engines (`neato` may work as well).